# probability and statistics - reaching a consensus using a stochastic matrix

Tags: probability, statistics

I am reading the article "Reaching a consensus" of Degroot: http://socsci2.ucsd.edu/~aronatas/project/academic/degroot%20consensus.pdf.
I don't have background in the field. Most of what is said there makes sense for me.

Except: in page 119 equation 3.3 it is assumed, that the matrix $P$ is constant. As I understood, the matrix $P^{n}$ describes weights that are given at the $n$'s iteration of the process.

> My question is: how come $P$ is the same matrix at each iteration. I mean, how come $F^{(n)}=PF^{(n-1)}$?